# jQuery's .each() looping

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, if-statement, each

I have this script where it loops through an array and its supposed to check if each of the values within the array is an email with this function:

```
function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

Supposed to look through array:

```
$.each(arrayEmail,function(i){

    var checkEmail = isEmail(arrayEmail[i]);
    if(checkEmail != false){
    alert(arrayEmail[i]);
    var message = $('#sendMsg textarea.emailMsg').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'ajax_inviteMsg.php',
            data: 'to='+$.trim(arrayEmail[i])+'&message='+message,
            success: function(data){
                  alert(data);
            }

    });
    }
});
```

The `alert(arrayEmail[i]);` after checking if email if false or not only displays first value, which tells me that it only iterates through the if statement one, however, I've tested the emails and should be working doesn't get passed through that if statement.

If the alert right after the each function, it iterates through the values corretly.

Again, the emails are true and should be iterating through the if statement as true.

I just want to know what I'm doing wrong that it only passes the if statement once if there's multiple values in the array.

Thanks

EDIT

I also have this before the each function

```
<div>test@gmail.com, fresh@hotmail.com</div>


var emails = $('div').text();
var arrayEmail = emails.split(',');
```

Comment: Put `alert(arrayEmail[i] + " " + isEmail(arrayEmail[i]));` before the if, there is likely something wrong with your regular expression.

Comment: @TomWijsman it functions like its supposed to. Also, I edited my OP to let you know that to get my values, I used this code inside a div

Comment: Please create a fiddle with some sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you split text of div element your array becomes this:
element0 = "test@gmail.com"
element1 = " fresh@hotmail.com"

2nd element has leading space and fails to match regular expression.

Try with this div: test@gmail.com,fresh@hotmail.com without space and you will understand.

On the end trim string before validating it.

Comment: In fact do this: var checkEmail = isEmail($.trim(arrayEmail[i])); and be done with it.

Comment: My issue is, what if someone inserts a space. these values are inputs, so I want user to have freedom if they want to use space or not. I like @VeljaRadenkovic answer, however, my second value is getting a false statement instead of being true? But it should be true because its a correct email address, any suggestions?

Comment: Its false because it doesnt match regexp pattern. It doesnt match regexp pattern because of leading space. If someone inputs space trim it by doing what I posted above: var checkEmail = isEmail($.trim(arrayEmail[i]));

Comment: You are welcome. BTW are you using any javascript debugging tool? Like firebug, or I believe chrome has one built in? It is easy to step through things like this.

Comment: hmm not as often, i should get in the habit of doing so... thanks for the tip!